# Security implications of plaintext-padding in an AEAD-scheme

Tags: authenticated-encryption, padding, pseudo-random-permutation, padding-oracle

Let's say I have a secure AEAD-scheme like ChaCha20/HMAC and my encrypted blobs need to match a fixed size:

Is it OK to apply some padding to my plaintext to match the block-size?

Can I use *any* reversible padding or should it provide some special properties?

---

The required ciphertext properties are:

- privacy
- integrity
- indistinguishability from random data